# ImapIdleChannelAdapter doesn't reconnect to IDLE after timeout

Tags: spring-integration, jakarta-mail, imap

I use ImapIdleChannelAdapter (6.1.0) for retrieving messages from exchange v4 email service and have noticed that after some period of time approximately 30m probably because IDLE connection lasts 30m usually, my channel loses connection as expected and doesn't reconnnect properly. I have very similar to defaults settings with `.shouldReconnectAutomatically(true)` which is actually default true also though.  I thought this is enough to rely on framework to reconnect or I'm missing the point somewhere? Not much information have found on it.

Spec and flow intialization:

```
...
       private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext; 
...
        ImapIdleChannelAdapterSpec imapIdleChannelAdapterSpec = Mail.imapIdleAdapter(url)
            .javaMailProperties(javaMailProperties)
            .javaMailAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            })
            .shouldReconnectAutomatically(true)
            .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(false)
            .autoCloseFolder(false)
            .shouldDeleteMessages(false);

        StandardIntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlow.from(imapIdleChannelAdapterSpec)
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG)
            .handle(...)
            .get();

        flowContext.registration(integrationFlow)
            .id("ImapFor" + imap.getUsername())
            .useFlowIdAsPrefix()
            .register();
```

Comment: A couple questions: 1. How does it work if you downgrade to `6.0.6`? 2. Share, please, what you have in logs around around that `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` when connection is lost?

Comment: thanks for the answer, 6.0.6 shows same behaviour.  Actually 30 minutes after last processed message that causes error. There is no information at all in logs related with disconnection. o.springframework.core.log.LogAccessor: waiting for mail was last

Comment: What do you mean with "last processed message that causes error"? I thought you said the connection is lost after IDLE and no reconnection.

Comment: Sorry for grammar mistake. I mean problem occurs if only adapter is out of messages for more than 30 minutes, it seems adapter silently loses connection and sleeps in that case, ignoring all futher messages, the only way to deal with it now is to keep sending messages with interval less than 30 minutes between them.

Comment: I see. OK. I'll look if there is anything we can do to "re-IDLE" in between...

Comment: There suppose to be a `Canceling IDLE` debug logging message from the `ImapMailReceiver`

Comment: Nah, no log, breakpoint on it is never reached too. Provided code snippet how I register my flow just in case there may be some problem with it.

Comment: Any explanation why do you need to do that dynamically? How does your `imapIdleChannelAdapterSpec` look? I mean what can I use on my side to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I do that dynamically because information about emails is stored in S3 storage and I manually register flow for each provided IMAP configuration from there. Provided spec also, gonna try it out yourself on another email provider.

Comment: OK. I see. Makes sense. Will try your approach with my GMail account today. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem against GMail, but I didn't get any lost connection. Perhaps GMail just doesn't time it out.

My problem was about a race condition with `TaskScheduler` and its single thread in the pool of an auto-configured by Spring Boot `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`: the `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` schedules a `ReceivingTask` which enters into an `IDLE` state and blocked. That `ReceivingTask` calls a `ImapMailReceiver` which schedules an `IdleCanceler` task. And since we are blocked in the `idle()` state, we don't let another task to be performed in the scheduler.

I fixed it like this in the `application.properties`:

```
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10
```

It is not clear, thought, from your question if you use Spring Boot or not.

Comment: Yes, I do use Spring boot. Gonna do some researches too, thank you for  the big effort and time spent!